# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un UPDATE a varias filas en MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, transacciones

Necesito transferir saldo de una cuenta a otra en MYSQL. La table tiene dos columnas una cuenta y otra de saldo. Primero necesito validar que la cuenta exista y que tenga saldo suficiente para realizar la trasferencia. Tengo el siguiente código.

```
UPDATE cuentas
SET saldo = saldo - 200
Where cuenta = "a" AND saldo >= 200;
Select * from cuentas;
```

El tema es que también necesito sumarle esos 200 a "b" sabiendo que "a" si tiene saldo suficiente, y eso es lo que nosé como hacer. Ya llevo días cabeceándome con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, tiene su miga En un caso hay que sumar, en el otro restar y, además, en filas diferentes. De ahí que primero hiciera una consulta para mostrar los incrementos de saldos de cada cuenta y después actualizara datos únicamente en la fila correspondiente:

```
UPDATE cuentas JOIN (
    SELECT cuenta,
      IF(cuenta='b' AND (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cuentas
          WHERE cuenta='a' AND saldo>=200
      ),200,
        IF(cuenta='a' AND saldo>=200,-200,0)
      ) incremento
      FROM cuentas  
  ) c1 USING(cuenta)
  set saldo=saldo+incremento;
```

Seguro que dándole alguna vuelta más encontramos una forma más limpia y fácil de entender, pero es lo que se me ha ocurrido sobre la marcha. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Aporto del dataset para hacer las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE cuentas(
  cuenta varchar(1),
  saldo float
  );
INSERT INTO cuentas (cuenta, saldo) VALUES
  ('a',200),('b',0),('c',300);
```

Y la consulta intermedia para calcular los incrementos de saldo en las diferentes cuentas:

```
SELECT cuenta,
  IF(cuenta='b' AND (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cuentas
      WHERE cuenta='a' AND saldo>=200
  ),200,
    IF(cuenta='a' AND saldo>=200,-200,0)
  ) incremento
  FROM cuentas
```

De la que se obtiene:

```
+--------+------------+
| cuenta | incremento |
+--------+------------+
| a      |       -200 |
| b      |        200 |
| c      |          0 |
+--------+------------+
```

En este punto ya únicamente quedaría aplicar este incremento a cada cuenta con un `UPDATE` con un `JOIN`.